# Get Type in QuickInfoSource

Tags: c#, quickinfo

i have a Class like this.

```
public static class MyTestClass
{
  [MyCustomAttribnute("MoreInformations")
  public static string MyProperty => "Sample";
}
```

I can use the class like this.

```
public static void Main()
{
  var myTest = MyTestClass.MyProperty;
}
```

Now i create a QuickInfoSource and i can get the text "MyTestClass.MyProperty" when i hover over "MyProperty". But i want do get the Type "MyTestClass" to get the customAttribute of "MyProperty".

anybody knows how to get the Type?
Here is my experimental Code of the "QuickInfoSource" class.

```
internal class TestQuickInfoSource : IAsyncQuickInfoSource
  {
    private TestQuickInfoSourceProvider m_provider;
    private ITextBuffer m_subjectBuffer;
    private Dictionary<string, string> m_dictionary;

    public TestQuickInfoSource(TestQuickInfoSourceProvider provider, ITextBuffer subjectBuffer)
    {
      m_provider = provider;
      m_subjectBuffer = subjectBuffer;

      //these are the method names and their descriptions
      m_dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
      m_dictionary.Add("add", "int add(int firstInt, int secondInt)\nAdds one integer to another.");
      m_dictionary.Add("subtract", "int subtract(int firstInt, int secondInt)\nSubtracts one integer from another.");
      m_dictionary.Add("multiply", "int multiply(int firstInt, int secondInt)\nMultiplies one integer by another.");
      m_dictionary.Add("divide", "int divide(int firstInt, int secondInt)\nDivides one integer by another.");
    }

    public async Task<QuickInfoItem> GetQuickInfoItemAsync(IAsyncQuickInfoSession session, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
      // Map the trigger point down to our buffer.
      SnapshotPoint? subjectTriggerPoint = session.GetTriggerPoint(m_subjectBuffer.CurrentSnapshot);
      if (!subjectTriggerPoint.HasValue)
      {
        return null;
      }

      ITextSnapshot currentSnapshot = subjectTriggerPoint.Value.Snapshot;
      SnapshotSpan querySpan = new SnapshotSpan(subjectTriggerPoint.Value, 0);

      //look for occurrences of our QuickInfo words in the span
      ITextStructureNavigator navigator = m_provider.NavigatorService.GetTextStructureNavigator(m_subjectBuffer);
      TextExtent extent = navigator.GetExtentOfWord(subjectTriggerPoint.Value);
      SnapshotSpan span = navigator.GetSpanOfPreviousSibling(querySpan);
      string searchText = extent.Span.GetText();
      string searchText2 = span.GetText();

      foreach (string key in m_dictionary.Keys)
      {
        int foundIndex = searchText.IndexOf(key, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
        if (foundIndex > -1)
        {
          string value;
          m_dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value);

          return new QuickInfoItem(session.ApplicableToSpan, value ?? string.Empty);
        }
      }

      return null; 
    }

    private bool m_isDisposed;
    public void Dispose()
    {
      if (!m_isDisposed)
      {
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        m_isDisposed = true;
      }
    }
  }
```